# why google.com not set includeSubDomains directive on HSTS response header?

Tags: http, security, httpresponse, hsts

why google.com not set includeSubDomains directive on http strict transport security response header ?

google.com HSTS resonse header is something like:

```
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=86400
```

Why not

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400; includeSubDomains
```

The second one should be more secure from my side, is that  right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is static**

Using Google Chrome, you can go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and Query different domains. Entering `google.com` and clicking on Query will bring back a list of results.

In that result list, you can see that `static_sts_include_subdomains` is true and `dynamic_sts_include_subdomains` is false. This is better than setting it dynamically, which is vulnerable to an attack whereby the very first time the browser requests the domain with `http://` (not `https://`) an adversary intercepts the communication. In order to overcome this weakness we have the static mode which allows for hard-coding HSTS records directly into the browser's source.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply, HSTS also supports preload directive, does that overcome the weakness ? not sure the static mode you mentioned ? is there any reference that I could read...? thanks again !

Comment: The `preload` flag indicates the site owner's consent to have their domain preloaded. The site owner still needs to then go and submit the domain to the list. Google also runs redirects on the first connection. The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.

Comment: You can also check this [cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet) from OWASP if you'd like to read more about it, but this is HSTS in general.

Comment: what is the difference dynamic_sts_include_subdomains and static_sts_include_subdomains .. thanks for your help !

Comment: Dynamic means that the browser has been instructed to enable HSTS by an HTTP response header (served over TLS). Static mode allows for hard-coding HSTS records directly into the browser's source (as mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is more secure to use `includeSubDomains`.

For example an attacker could set up and use a subdomain (e.g. hacked.google.com) and access that over HTTP and and use that to access or override cookies set at top level domain (google.com) even though that top level domain is secured with HSTS. Of course if you're using `Secure` attribute on your cookies then this might not be an issue but this is just one example of why to use `includeSubDomains`.

You cannot set the `includeSubDomains` attrribute unless all subdomains are available on HTTPS (obviously). So if Google had blog.google.com and had still not upgraded this to HTTPS then that might explain why they would not use  `includeSubDomains` at the top level domain.

However, as @Horkine rightly points out, Google preloads their domains into the Chrome browser code (and that preload list is also picked up by other browsers) so this HTTP header isn't used for modern browsers.

Weirldy there are some inconsitencies between the preloaded version and the HTTP HTTP Headers version. That is very odd to be honest. Incidentally these discrepancies also [breaks their own rules for preloading](https://hstspreload.org/).

**www.google.com**

- The preloaded version for www.google.com **does have** the `includeSubDomains` attribute.
- The Strict-Transport-Security HTTP Header version **does not** have  the `includeSubDomains` attribute but not the `preload` attribute.

**google.com**

- The preloaded version for google.com **does have** the `includeSubDomains` attribute
- No Strict-Transport-Security HTTP header is published.

Why these inconsistencies? We can only guess:

- It could be that they never got round to updating their HTTP Header after finishing the upgrade to all their sites?
- Or it could be because some of the apps do browser detection for older browsers (which do not include the preload code, but does understand the HSTS header) and redirects older browsers to http://old.google.com for some reason?
- Or it could be region specific?

All of it is a guess really, as only Google can answer and I'm not aware of any documentation of what they use on their own site or why.

But, yes, to answer you last question it is more secure to include `includeSubDomains` (if possible) and it is even more secure  to preload (though not without risks unless you are 100% confident you are only using HTTPS).